# Is there a coordinate free proof of the Morrey--Kohn--Hormander identity?

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, integration, stein-manifolds

The [Morrey--Kohn--Hormander identity](http://www.google.com/search?q=Morrey--Kohn--Hormander+identity) is the key to proving vanishing/existence results on bounded pseudoconvex domains in $\mathbb{C}^n$, or more generally, Stein domains.  See, for instance, the classical references [Kohn](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=153030) and [Hörmander](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=179443), or the more recent exposition of [Straube](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2603659).

There is no lack of derivations of this identity in the literature, yet my question is still simply a "reference request" for a proof of this identity which doesn't use "calculation in coordinates" as the main tool in the proof.  At first glance, it seems such a proof should not be that hard, since the proof is "just integration by parts", but on the other hand going from a calculation in coordinates to the corresponding coordinate free calculation is often nontrivial.

I have almost worked out a coordinate free proof of the identity (it remains "just" to put the boundary terms in the correct form).  I hope, though, that such a proof has already been written, so I can cite it and check that what I've done so far is correct.  In particular, I'm looking for a proof which gives a coordinate free calculation of the boundary term in the identity (I already know how to derive the interior terms from the Bochner--Kodaira--Nakano identity and some Kähler identities).

Comment: You can find the boundary terms on a complex manifold computed using differential geometric methods in the paper of Andreotti Vesentini Pub IHES vol 25 pages 80-139 .See also their erratum.This will still involve debauch of indices .See especially page 112 of their paper